# MySite and could not load user profile

Tags: 2010, user-profile, my-site

Got a really strange problem here.  All of a sudden users cannot access their mysite.  I get the could not load user profile error.  Strangely there doesnt seem to be anything in the logs relating to the correlation id presented.  Also when I look at the profiles in CA, if I take a copy of the URL to a users mysite I can access it no problem.  I can also sign in as a different user from the CA server and get to my own mysite no problem.  Looking on-line I've followed all the guidance and everything looks fine to me.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Can't find anything of substance in the logs

Comment: Please check the server time. All the servers should have same time frame. Regards
Gyan Shukla

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps given below :

1) Login to Central Administrations.

2) Click Application Management link.

3) In Service Applications click Manage services on server link.

4) Start User Profile Synchronization Service. If its already start, stop it and start again.

5) Then go to service application page and click on your user profile.

6) In Synchronization , click on Configure Synchronization Connections and edit and update your connection.

7) My Site Settings, click Setup My Sites link and again update your all settings.

8) No perform IISReset

check your mysite would be open.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this problem on two different instances.

First of all check that you have installed My Site Host like this:
https://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1313/configuring-my-sites-in-sharepoint-2010

In my case on the first instance it was missing the search site configured correctly. I've configured it as in the link bellow:

http://ntcoder.com/bab/2017/06/13/configure-sharepoint-searchcenter-url/

On the second instance I had sharepoint 2013 installed on sql server 2019 and one of the functions returned an error:

UserProfile.RetrieveUser() Exception (UserId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'): System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
SqlCommand: 'dbo.profile_GetUserProfileData'
Exception occurred loading user profile (/Person.aspx?accountname=username): Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileException: An error was encountered while retrieving the user profile

The error comes from User Profile Service Application_ProfileDB procedure profile_GetViewerRights.
In this procedure replace:
RETURN dbo.GetViewerRights(@partitionID, @RecordId, @ViewerRecordId, @ViewerNTName, @ManagerNTName, @correlationId)

WITH

DECLARE @result int
select @result = dbo.GetViewerRights(@partitionID, @RecordId, @ViewerRecordId, @ViewerNTName, @ManagerNTName, @correlationId)
return @result

Hope this helps

Good Luck